# Name for number of unique items in a multiset which appear only once

Tags: terminology, multisets

Question about terminology describing finite multisets.

What is the proper term for the number of items which have a frequency of one? Are they called singletons? Cardinality of singletons?  i.e. {a,a,b,c} would be 2 as {b} and {c} only appear once.

Although, I've seen the term cardinality defined both as (i) number of unique elements, and (2) number of items, depending on context; also singleton is defined as a set with only one element, {x}, not necessarily the number of elements in a multiset  which have multiplicity of one.

The number of unique entries which appear only once is called the ...

> {a,a,b,c} -> 2
> {a,a,b,b} -> 0

(There may be another term for the set of such elements?)

Comment: As you said, a singleton usually means a set with only one element

Answer (score 1):

Multisets aren't particularly common (probably because they share terminology with regular sets in ways that can make statements unclear), so the terminology isn't very standardized. If $X$ is a multiset, then the quantity you're describing is the number of elements of $X$ of multiplicity $1$. There's no shorter name for it that would be widely understood.